# How to handle empty array in next.js react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

react is throwing me an error that says error: type is not supported. I think its throwing this error because if one of my array items is empty, it cant read empty array.. when my **blog.author** is empty, **getJsonItem()** syntax just could not pick up any empty value and this would throw an error.. How can i write a condition that even if its empty, it will still run the script?

```
const author_url_slug = urlSlug(blog.author);
// Match consultant name
const consultants = (await Collection('consultants')).filter(function (i) {
   return (
       urlSlug(i.url_slug) === author_url_slug
)
});
const all_consultants = consultants.orderBy('order').getJsonItem();
```

Edited: now the all_consultants is not defined
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd check if author_url_slug isn't empty before processing, the below example should do the trick.

```
const author_url_slug = urlSlug(blog.author);
let all_consultants = [];

if (author_url_slug) {
  const consultants = (await Collection('consultants')).filter(function (i) {
    return urlSlug(i.url_slug) === author_url_slug;
  });

  all_consultants = consultants.orderBy('order').getJsonItem();
} else {
  console.log("Author URL slug is empty.");
}
```

Comment: now the error shows all_consultants is not define sir

Comment: i've just updated on the question with a screenshot.. it seems that once the cost is in a condition, it will not read the all_consultants

Comment: Put `let all_consultants = [];` before the if statement and remove the declaration on the else statement. My apologies forgot to include that.